# Cannot create systemd script for Puma

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, puma, systemd

I created a service script named `"puma.service"` in `/etc/systemd/system/` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple

User=ubuntu

WorkingDirectory=/home/username/appdir/current

ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc "/home/username/appdir/current/sbin/puma -C /home/username/appdir/current/config/puma.rb /home/username/appdir/current/config.ru"

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I enabled the service and when started, I'm getting the following log from systemctl:

```
● puma.service - Puma HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/puma.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-12-14 10:09:46 UTC; 12min ago
  Process: 16889 ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc cd /home/username/appdir/current && bundle exec puma -C /home/username/appdir..
 Main PID: 16889 (code=exited, status=127)

Dec 14 10:09:46 ip-172-31-29-40 systemd[1]: puma.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Dec 14 10:09:46 ip-172-31-29-40 systemd[1]: puma.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 14 10:09:46 ip-172-31-29-40 systemd[1]: puma.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 14 10:09:46 ip-172-31-29-40 systemd[1]: puma.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 14 10:09:46 ip-172-31-29-40 systemd[1]: Stopped Puma HTTP Server.
Dec 14 10:09:46 ip-172-31-29-40 systemd[1]: puma.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 14 10:09:46 ip-172-31-29-40 systemd[1]: Failed to start Puma HTTP Server.
```

Although, when I give the command in SSH terminal the server started and was running perfect. Is there any changes I have to make in the service file?

**Note:**

1. I have changed the dirnames for your convenience.
2. I did some research and the cause of status 127 is due to the executable not in the path. But, I guess that won't be a problem.

Can you shed some light?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the problem and changed the ExecStart as mentioned below and it worked like a charm:

```
ExecStart=/home/username/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec puma -e production -C ./config/puma.rb config.ru
PIDFile=/home/username/appdir/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid
```

`bundle` should be taken from the rbenv shims and also the puma's config file (`config/puma.rb`) and application's config file (`config.ru`) can be given in relative path.

Comment: Any idea if this should work differently in rvm? I tried this using the corresponding paths in rvm and still get the same result

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. Never tried rvm, all my deployment scripts were in rbenv.

Comment: @Carl Try /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/[your-gemset-name]/bin/bundle

Comment: Excellent , note for me I only had to change the bundle path (using rbenv) ExecStart=/home/username/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec puma -e production -C ./config/puma.rb

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to specify a PID file and systemd will take a look at that file to check on service status.

Here's how we use this in our scripts (adapted to your given sample)

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc '/home/username/appdir/current/sbin/puma -C /home/username/appdir/current/config/puma.rb /home/username/appdir/current/config.ru --pidfile /home/username/appdir/current/tmp/pids/puma.pid'
PIDFile=/home/username/appdir/current/tmp/pids/puma.pid
```

Take note that you might have to configure `--pidfile` via your `-C puma.rb` file instead of passing it an as parameter. I'm just showing it here to illustrate that `--pidfile` (in puma config) should be the same as `PIDFile` in the service file.

As for why the error message is that way, I'm not sure myself and is interested in the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

For `rvm` users try with

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user_name
Group=user_name

WorkingDirectory=/home/user_name/apps/app_name/current
Environment=RAILS_ENV=production

ExecStart=/home/user_name/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-3.1.2@app_name do bundle exec --keep-file-descriptors puma -C /home/user_name/apps/app_name/current/config/puma/production.rb
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR1 $MAINPID

StandardOutput=append:/home/user_name/apps/app_name/current/log/puma_access.log
StandardError=append:/home/user_name/apps/app_name/current/log/puma_error.log
SyslogIdentifier=app_name-puma

Restart=always
KillMode=process


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

if you are not using a gemset change

```
ExecStart=/home/user_name/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-3.1.2@app_name ....
```

to

```
ExecStart=/home/user_name/.rvm/bin/rvm default
```